# How to skip lines and how to read specific information in the lines in a .txt file (Java, Windows)

Tags: java, filereader

I was wondering how to make it so that the first line is skipped and also how to skip the player number at the start and read the first name, last name and position only.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class AFLTeamMember {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File fileContents = new File("WesternBulldogs.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fileContents);
        String PlayerFirstName = inputFile.nextLine();
        String PlayerLastName = inputFile.nextLine();
        String PlayerPostition = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(PlayerFirstName + " " + PlayerLastName + "," + " " + PlayerPostition); 
    }
}
```

The text file:

```
Western Bulldogs
Luke Beveridge, COACH
10, Easton Wood, FB
42, Alex Keath, FB
15, Taylor Duryea, FB
35, Caleb Daniel, HB
12, Zaine Cordy, HB
31, Bailey Dale, HB
6, Bailey Smith, C
21, Tom Liberatore, C
7, Lachie Hunter, C
19, Cody Weightman, HF
33, Aaron Naughton, HF
1, Adam Treloar, HF
39, Jason Johannisen, FF
44, Tim English, FF
29, Mitch Hannan, FF
8, Stefan Martin, FOL
11, Jack Macrae, FOL
4, Marcus Bontempelli, FOL, c
34, Bailey Williams, IC
5, Josh Dunkley, IC
37, Roarke Smith, IC
13, Josh Schache, IC
```

Comment: *"so that the first line is skipped"* - call that `inputFile.nextLine()` and put it nowhere? *"how to skip the player number at the start and read the first name, last name and position only"* - the `nextLine` reads the entire line, after you read the entire line, put it output in regex or split the strings directly by comma (`,`).

Comment: use `.nextLine()` to get a line. use a counter variable starting at 0, if 0 skip the line and do not process. If it is not 0, you can use `.split()` to split by a delimiter to get a string array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close the file after processing it. I recommend using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for that.

In my opinion, your task lends itself to [streams](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2.html). Refer to method `useStreams` in the below code.

As suggested in the comments, use method [split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) (of class `java.lang.String`) – which uses [regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html).

In the below code, method `main` uses a non-streams approach.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class AFLTeamMember {
    private static void useStreams() throws IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get("WesternBulldogs.txt");
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            lines.skip(1)
                 .map(l -> l.split(", "))
                 .forEach(a -> {
                     if (a.length == 3)
                         System.out.println(a[1] + ", " + a[2]);
                     else
                         System.out.println(a[0] + ", " + a[1]);
                               });
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        useStreams();
        File fileContents = new File("WesternBulldogs.txt");
        try (Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fileContents)) {
            int count = 0;
            while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = inputFile.nextLine();
                if (count < 1) {
                    // Skip the first line of the file.
                    count++;
                }
                else if (count < 2) {
                    // Print the second line of the file as is.
                    System.out.println(line);
                    count++;
                }
                else {
                    String[] parts = line.split(", ", 2);
                    System.out.println(parts[1]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output when I run the above code:

```
Luke Beveridge, COACH
Easton Wood, FB
Alex Keath, FB
Taylor Duryea, FB
Caleb Daniel, HB
Zaine Cordy, HB
Bailey Dale, HB
Bailey Smith, C
Tom Liberatore, C
Lachie Hunter, C
Cody Weightman, HF
Aaron Naughton, HF
Adam Treloar, HF
Jason Johannisen, FF
Tim English, FF
Mitch Hannan, FF
Stefan Martin, FOL
Jack Macrae, FOL
4, Marcus Bontempelli
Bailey Williams, IC
Josh Dunkley, IC
Roarke Smith, IC
Josh Schache, IC

Luke Beveridge, COACH
Easton Wood, FB
Alex Keath, FB
Taylor Duryea, FB
Caleb Daniel, HB
Zaine Cordy, HB
Bailey Dale, HB
Bailey Smith, C
Tom Liberatore, C
Lachie Hunter, C
Cody Weightman, HF
Aaron Naughton, HF
Adam Treloar, HF
Jason Johannisen, FF
Tim English, FF
Mitch Hannan, FF
Stefan Martin, FOL
Jack Macrae, FOL
Marcus Bontempelli, FOL, c
Bailey Williams, IC
Josh Dunkley, IC
Roarke Smith, IC
Josh Schache, IC
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the links as well, if it's not too much trouble could you explain how the values in the If statements affect the lines in the txt file

Comment: @Manish added comments to the code in my answer. Hope that answers your question. I assume you are a [Western Bulldogs](https://www.westernbulldogs.com.au/) fan.